# Stop PHPStorm from cutting/copying the entire line if nothing is selected

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, editing

If I set the caret on a line and accidentally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, then the entire line is cut/copied, since there is no selection.

This can be very annoying, and can often times destroy code in the clipboard which I wanted to paste. I'd expect nothing to happen if nothing is selected. How can this be turned off?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Go to **Registry** screen: `Help | Find Action...` and search for `registry` there
2. Once there -- find and activate `editor.skip.copy.and.cut.for.empty.selection` entry.

[image]

Comment: It's a shame that a few annoying options are so well hidden... You might want to add that the check box in the top left corner of the `Find action` popup needs to be checked for the Registry option to appear

Comment: 1) There has been quite a lot of tickets and people (I'd say over 100 votes in total) asking to have current behaviour (as it's available in other editors) and so far only one ticket (known to me) which asked to have ability to turn it off (I'm talking about JB's Issue Tracker). With such big difference in people's needs, there is no real need to have separate GUI option in Settings to satisfy just a few people: Settings screen is already crowded with options ..

Comment: 2) Now you know about such "hidden" place (which is done like that for a reason -- it contains options that only very small number of people using it) -- you should have no more issues with finding them again. 3) But if you feel that "Find Action" should search there as well -- you are welcome to submit your opinion as a ticket into their Issue Tracker.

Comment: I do like applications changing the way we think. Don't mind going to a "hidden place" to tick a checkbox as long as the option is still available and I'm still learning the "new" way. This is as good as how useful RegEdit *was* (now a Linux user) for me.

Comment: WebStorm 7.0.3 click `ctrl` `alt` `shift` `slash` to get to **Registry** where activate **editor.skip.copy.and.cut.for.empty.selection** which LazyOne mentioned

Comment: Thanks so much!  This setting really needs to be surfaced properly as this default behavior is beyond frustrating.