# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select current line in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

In PhpStorm there is shortcut to extend selecting `ctrl + w`. It there shortcut to select all current line? I looking for something that works like `ctrl + l` in Sublime?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Such action is available ... but assigned shortcut (if any) depends on actual keymap used.

In any case:

1. `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`
2. Locate `Editor Actions | Select line at Caret` entry (HINT: use local search box)
3. Assign any shortcut you wish (or use provided one, if that keymap has one)

[image]

---

**P.S.**
If you want to select current line to copy/cut it as a next step ... then you can just use Copy or Cut straight away -- it will copy/cut current line if no selection is made (default behaviour -- can be turned off via [hidden setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702430/783119)).

Comment: P.S. was quite enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Yes - go to **Settings > Keymap** and search for "Select line at caret". You can map it to any keyboard shortcut you like by right-clicking it and select "Add Keyboard Shortcut".

If you try to assign a keyboard shortcut which is already assigned to something else, PhpStorm will let you decide whether to continue or change your keybind.