# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select a code from start to end in current line?

Tags: phpstorm

I know these shortcuts:

1. <kbd>Ctrl + W</kbd>: it selects code until the an space

   [image]
2. Select line at caret (I don't remember its shortcut key): it selects whole line with extra spaces:

   [image]

But I'm looking for a shortcut that only select code from **start to end** like this :

[image]

Different between "Select line at caret" vs Mine request:

[differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkBaV.gif)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468490/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-select-current-line-in-phpstorm This seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Challe No, Read my post again. "Select line at caret" would selects the whole line with extra spaces (look at second screen shot) but i'm looking for a thing that select start to end code.

Comment: Record yourself a Macro then... and assign custom shortcut to it.

Comment: How would what you're looking for be different from "select line at caret"? I mean, whatever you do afterwards won't be affected by where the caret is. Or am I missing an obvious use case?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca see the differences : https://imgur.com/a/y59SswO

Comment: @LazyOne if there is a thing that take my curose to forst and last letter in line then i could make macro , any idea?

Comment: @Diok so "select line at caret" actually doesn't select?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it does, But it selects with "Extra Spaces". if you grab the line with extra spaces your codes immediately jump to the next line afterwards please see this : https://imgur.com/a/y59SswO

Comment: `Home` and then `Shift + End` ?

Comment: There is also dedicated `Delete to Line End` action, has no shortcut by default. Based on your small video it should be be useful for you (since you seem to want to select and delete current line and type other text instead).

Answer (score 0):

Well, Ideavim works on PhpStorm. Provides vim experience in InteliJ . 
Using this plugin, `<SHIFT-V>` selects a line.

Just be aware that you might need to know vim to use it further. 
Anyway, it is a cool plugin.