# How to stop WebStorm from copying white space

Tags: webstorm

If I copy something using `Ctrl + C` and want to paste it in a fresh line using `Ctrl + V` but press `Ctrl + C` again, in the fresh line, by mistake, it will replace previously copied stuff with nothing. I want WebStorm to not to copy whitespace (or nothing).

How to do this? It extremely annoying.

**Edit:**

Here is what I want:

If I place the cursor on an empty line and press `Ctrl+c` without making any selection following should happen:

1.If the line is empty (or just whitespace), don't copy it.

2.If line is non-empty, copy it

**There is no reason to copy nothing**

Comment: You mean -- even if you place caret on a non-empty line (it's easier for me to see what's happening . as I cannot see what you are seeing) and you will not have any selection made and you press `Ctrl+C` or `Ctrl+X` it will copy/cut that line under caret?

Comment: @LazyOne I have made edit. Please have a look

Comment: Do not know about such option. I may only offer you a way to disable the copy completely when there is no selection made -- might be better than nothing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702430/783119

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks. That helped a lot.

Comment: In such case -- can I mark this question as duplicate?

Comment: @LazyOne I won't call it a duplicate. But if you think so, go ahead.

Comment: Well .. if it's resolves your issue -- then it is (keep in mind -- there is no separate option that would work for "whitespace/empty lines only" case). If you want to possibly see other opinions (who knows, maybe some JetBrains dev will see this question and has some better knowledge) then we may keep it as is. But as per my knowledge, the best that may happen is somebody will provide you a link to a ticket that describe your desired behaviour (could not find such ticket myself though).

Comment: BTW -- you can still use "Edit | Paste from History..."